# Can't build/run PEGKit ParserGenApp without valid Mac Developer Certificate

Tags: ios8, code-signing, osx-yosemite, parsekit, pegkit

I'm using PEGKit to generate a parser for an iOS app I am developing. To do so, I need to run a helper app (ParserGenApp) that is distributed with PEGKit to generate the parser source code. I've followed the instruction here:

https://github.com/itod/PEGKitMiniMathTutorial

But whenever I try to build/run the app, I get an error "No signing identity found!"

I have an iOS developer certificate, but not Mac developer certificate. I'm able to build/run other sample mac apps locally.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. PEGKit project was set to use code-signing when it shouldn't have been.

Comment: Developer of PEGKit here. Yes you're right. I accidentally checked in the project with code-signing turned on. It was unintentional. Sorry about that.